# Does Adwhirl supports Smaato on Android Platform?

Tags: android, sdk, adapter, ads, adwhirl

I had recently implemented ads for my android game app. Through AdWhirl, I have integrated Admob and Millennial Media. Now, I am looking for the possibility to integrate ads Smaato through Adwhirl as I have integrated Admob & Millennial Media.

The AdWhirl SDK which I have downloaded does not have any adapter class for Smaato so far. I also want to know whether it is possible to write adapter class for Smaato & integrate with Adwhirl SDK?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Atul Prakash Singh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have build such an adapter for iOS but not for Android yet. It should be possible to write it for Android as well.

Regards
Michael
Smaato Inc.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write function for Custom event on top hierarchy.

This is a sample code :satrt_SUMO
May it helps you.

---

```
public class XXXX extends Activity implements AdWhirlInterface {
SOMABanner mBanner;<br>
AdWhirlLayout MAdWhirlLayout;
   ......

@Override
public void adWhirlGeneric() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
com.smaato.SOMA.AdListener  adls=new com.smaato.SOMA.AdListener(){
    @Override
    public void onFailedToReceiveAd(AdDownloader arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //AdWhirl will now load from another ad network you have added
        mBanner.setAutoRefresh(false);
        mBanner.removeAdListener(adls);
        MAdWhirlLayout.rollover();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveAd(AdDownloader arg0, SOMAReceivedBanner arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.v("SUMO Listener", "Ad Received.");
        //AdWhirl will wait for 30 seconds or so before it will start requesting ad
        mBanner.setAutoRefresh(false);
        mBanner.removeAdListener(adls);
        MAdWhirlLayout.adWhirlManager.resetRollover();
        MAdWhirlLayout.rotateThreadedDelayed();
    }
};

    public void start_SUMO() {
        mBanner= new SOMABanner(this);
         mBanner.setPublisherId(**your publisher ID**);
         mBanner.setAdSpaceId(**your space ID**);
         mBanner.asyncLoadNewBanner();
         mBanner.setAutoRefresh(true);
         mBanner.addAdListener(adls);
                     MAdWhirlLayout.pushSubView(mBanner);
             }
.....
```